# How many comparisons does cocktail sort use?

Tags: sorting, bubble-sort

Title. I am confused about the number of comparisons for the cocktail sort. Bubble sort uses n*(n-1)/2 comparisons, how many does the cocktail sort use?

Comment: How did you figure out the `n*(n-1)/2`? And can you do that for cocktail sort too?

Answer (score 1):

> Bubble sort uses `n*(n-1)/2` comparisons

Not if you have implemented it correctly!

This is the pseudo-code for standard Bubble sort:

```
procedure bubbleSort(A : list of sortable items )
    n = length(A)
    repeat
        swapped = false
        for i = 1 to n-1 inclusive do
            /* if this pair is out of order */
            if A[i-1] > A[i] then
                /* swap them and remember something changed */
                swap( A[i-1], A[i] )
                swapped = true
            end if
        end for
    until not swapped
end procedure
```

(Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Pseudocode_implementation))

As you can see, Bubble sort stops when it makes a pass through the list / array without swapping any elements.  Thus the number of swaps is `(n - 1) * p` when `p` is the number of passes.  `p` will be less or equal to `n` and will depend on how ordered the input array is.

A complexity analysis gives `O(N^2)` as the worst and average case complexity and `O(N)` as the best case.

The same Wikipedia article describes an optimized Bubble sort that performs *at most* `(n-1)*(n-2)/2` comparisons, with `n-1` as the best case.  That is a roughly 2-fold improvement on standard Bubble sort.

Cocktail Shaker sort is described as an *alternative* optimization to Bubble sort.  It also gives a roughly 2-fold improvement over standard Bubble sort.

(Source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_shaker_sort))

---

Note that it is not possible to give a precise formula for the number of comparisons for *any* of these sort algorithms.  In each case, the number of comparisons depends on the actual input array, not just the number of elements.  We can only give precise formulae for the best and worst cases.

Comment: I see, then I haven't been precise enough. I am looking for the worst case number of comparisons. For bubble sort, it's still the formula I posted, and for cocktail sort, I still don't know.

Comment: The worst case for shaker and bubble sorts is when the input is sorted in the reverse order.  You should be able to work the number of swaps ...

Comment: Thank you, this helped. It's the same as for bubble sort in the worst case.